# What was the first movie to feature zombie babies?

Tags: history-of, zombie

I was watching the Talking Dead for the Walking Dead season two finale, and they talked about not actually being able to show a child being shot.  But they have shown zombie children.  But this made me think:

Assuming there have been zombie TV shows or movies which shows a baby, infant, or toddler which has been zombified, which was the first one?

Comment: this edit largely invalidates the existing accepted answer.

Comment: @ThePopMachine - I was actually puzzled by the comment you're referring to from *Talking Dead*.  They *said* they couldn't show a kid being shot, but they have shown at least three kids being shot.  1. Zombie girl with teddy bear (first episode of season one). 2. Carl (first or second episode of season two). 3. Zombie Sophia (Midseason finale, season two).

Comment: @ThePopMachine I don't remember if we really saw #1 happening, but we *definitely* saw #2 in detail, and #3 from a distance.

Comment: @WadCheber:   Noted and changed -- that was not my edit.

Comment: @ThePopMachine - I know, and I just retracted my close vote.  It is no longer a dupe.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because a new question should be asked instead of repurposing an old one.

Comment: Reopen.  No longer a dupe.  The other question is about kids, this one is about babies.

Comment: @SeanDuggan look at the history.   This question was always about babies until onewho drove by and changed it for no known  reason.

Comment: Right, but it changed from "list of films that include zombie babies" to "first movie to have zombie babies".

Comment: @SeanDuggan:   No.   It was never "list of films".   It was "are they any".   Then people get on their high-horse about "oh, this is a list question, let's close it because we can" and then someone has to add some qualification to make sure no one can make that ridiculous claim.    Honestly, this whole misinterpretation of "list question" is ridiculous and keeps recurring.

Comment: {nods} Ultimately, the current question does not match the accepted answer. Either the question needs to be changed back or the answer needs to be unaccepted. Personally, I think that you just need to post a new question and that will settle everything.

Comment: @SeanDuggan:   What's your suggested wording?

Comment: BTW everyone, this question predates the supposed dupe (which it isn't) by 3.5 years !

Comment: @ThePopMachine:
I'm suggesting just writing a question with the question of "What was the first movie to show zombie babies on screen?" probably with a clarification on what you consider the criteria for what a "baby" is in-context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dawn of the Dead (2004), and Braindead are two zombie movies I know have zombified babies in them, if you want spoilers there are some clips on youtube.

Braindead isn't very serious, and not exactly a traditional zombie movie, but it's well worth seeing if you haven't already!

Comment: Braindead (also known as Dead Alive) is a fantastic movie!  It kind of makes you wonder how Peter Jackson ever got the permission to make the Lord of the Rings movies, though....

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how you define the word "zombie", Dawn, the ill-fated baby from *Trainspotting* (1996), might qualify.  She isn't a zombie in the popularly accepted sense, because she doesn't eat anyone, and she is actually just a plain old dead baby, but during Mark Renton's heroin-withdrawal-instigated hallucination sequence, her corpse crawls across the ceiling to torment him.

Strictly speaking, it doesn't really matter whether Dawn is technically a zombie or not, because the movie *Dead Alive!* (1992) includes a baby who is [definitely](http://www.avclub.com/article/he-has-his-fathers-eyes-21-creepy-babies-in-film-a-40679) a zombie, by any definition of the word, and it predates *Trainspotting* by almost 4 years.  Bizarrely, this movie was one of the earliest efforts from the man who would later go on to direct the smash hit *The Lord of the Rings* and *The Hobbit* series, Peter Jackson.

There are earlier contenders, however:

[Burial Ground:  The Nights of Terror](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burial_Ground:_The_Nights_of_Terror) (1981)

[Redneck Zombies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redneck_Zombies) (1986-1987)

[Pet Sematary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pet_Sematary_(film)) (1989)

In most of these cases, everything hinges upon how one defines the words "zombie" and "baby":  I think *Redneck Zombies* best fits both categories, but the zombie "baby" in *Burial Ground* is actually a toddler at the very least.  On the other hand, the "zombie" baby in *Pet Sematary* might not be considered a true zombie - he's a toddler, and a young one at that, and he died and was reanimated, and he proceeded to kill everyone he met, but he didn't eat anyone, and he wasn't the typical stupid zombie (in fact, he was quite clever, in a monstrous and sadistic way).

### In any case, the first movie to feature a zombie baby was *possibly* one of the above, although considering the decades of low budget zombie movies that have passed since the genre became popular, it is entirely possible that an earlier zombie baby movie exists somewhere.  The most we can say with certainty is that the first zombie baby appeared onscreen no later than the mid-80's.